# Word slice riddle #2

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> With three I am close to bottom,
>
> With four i move free,
>
> With five i go down further,
>
> With all six i am found in a tree.

**Tell me. what am I?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is

> FLOWER

With three I am close to bottom,

> LOW

With four i move free,

> FLOW

With five i go down further,

> LOWER

With all six i am found in a tree.

> FLOWER

Comment: you got it, this is correct